# Creating a pyinstaller executable that uses virtualenv imported modules

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.7

So, the title basically covers my question.  I've created a project using virtualenv, e.g. I have to

```
source ./env/bin/activate
```

to run my script.

When I try creating an executable using:

```
pyinstaller --onefile <myscript.py>
```

None of the virtualenv packages are included; just the ones that are installed globally. I have a requirements.txt file that contains all of the modules I need.  Is there a way to have pyinstaller point to that for the needed modules, or is there another way?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629486/how-can-i-create-the-minimum-size-executable-with-pyinstaller

Answer (score 20):

As Valentino pointed out by looking at [How can I create the minimum size executable with pyinstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48629486/5750078)

You have to run PyIntaller from inside the virtual environment:

```
(venv_test) D:\testenv>pyinstaller
```

Comment: And your finished file will now be in the virtual environment's "dist" directory if not specified (e.g., "D:/testenv/dist"

Answer (score 2):

## How to solve the not importing modules from the virtual environment

The virtual environment saves modules in a different directory than the global module directory. If you are using Windows like me, you can find the modules directory here:

`C:\Users\<your username>\.virtualenvs\<your project name>\Lib\site-packages`

When you find your virtualenv directory, run this command instead of this simple command(`pyinstaller <script>.py`):

```bash
pyinstaller --paths "C:\Users\<your username>\.virtualenvs\<your project name>\Lib\site-packages" --hidden-import <module name that should be import> <your script name>.py
```

- To export just one file you can add this: `-F` or `--onefile`
- As many modules as you can add to be imported by adding more `--hidden-import` flags and module name

#### Flag description

`--paths`: The pyinstaller will search for imports here

`--hidden-import`: Which modules should be imported by pyinstaller from the path